# Nested table checkbox check/Uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a page with nested table and checkbox for checking all the table cell `<td>`. And checkbox for each table cell `<td>` for checking respective cell.

What I'm trying to do is

1. **CheckAll** checkbox checks/uncheck all the **parent** and **child** checkbox
2. Uncheck a **parent** checkbox unchecks **CheckALL** checkbox and unchecks all the **child** checkbox
3. Check a **parent** checkbox checks all **child** checkbox and finds out if all other **parent** checkbox are checked or not, to check **CheckALL** checkbox
4. checking a **child** checkbox should check the respective **parent**
5. unchecking a **child** checkbox should check if siblings are checked, if not checked **parent** checbox should get unchecked and if **checkALL** checkbox is checked it should get unchecked too.

I'm unable to do this.

Here is what I have tried.

html:

```
<table class="table table-striped tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr colspan="2">
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkedAll">
      </th>
      <th>Check/UnCheck ALL Boxes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkParent">
      </td>
      <td>1KWT</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0">
        <table class="innertable" style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 50px;border: 1px solid #d0d0d0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Sub</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkChild" style="margin-top: -3px"> </td>
              <td>1KWT1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkChild" style="margin-top: -3px"> </td>
              <td>1KWT2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkParent" style="margin-top: -3px"> </td>
      <td>1OMN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding: 0">
        <table class="innertable" style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 50px;border: 1px solid #d0d0d0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
            <th></th>
              <th>Sub</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkChild" style="margin-top: -3px"> </td>
              <td>1OMN1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkChild" style="margin-top: -3px"> </td>
              <td>1OMN2</td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#checkedAll").change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      $(".checkParent, .checkChild").each(function(){
        this.checked=true;
      });              
    }else{
      $(".checkParent, .checkChild").each(function(){
        this.checked=false;
      });              
    }
  });

  $(".checkParent").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
      var isAllChecked = 0;
      $(".checkParent").each(function(){
        if(!this.checked)
           isAllChecked = 1;
      }) 
      $(".checkChild").prop("checked", true);
      if(isAllChecked == 0){ $("#checkedAll").prop("checked", true); }     
    }else {
      $("#checkedAll, .checkChild").prop("checked", false);

    }
  });

  $(".checkChild").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    $(".checkParent").prop("checked", true);

    }else {
      $(".checkParent").prop("checked", false);

    }
  });


});
```

link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4zhhpwva/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it. Improvement's are welcomed. Here is the updated script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#checkedAll").change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(".checkParent, .checkChild").each(function() {
        this.checked = true;
      });
    } else {
      $(".checkParent, .checkChild").each(function() {
        this.checked = false;
      });
    }
  });

  $(".checkParent").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var isAllChecked = 0;
      $(".checkParent").each(function() {
        if (!this.checked)
          isAllChecked = 1;
      })
      $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".checkChild").prop("checked", true);
      if (isAllChecked == 0) {
        $("#checkedAll").prop("checked", true);
      }
    } else {
      $("#checkedAll").prop("checked", false);
      $(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".checkChild").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });

  $(".checkChild").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

      var isChildChecked = 0;
      $(".checkChild").each(function() {
        if (!this.checked)
          isChildChecked = 1;
      });
      if (isChildChecked == 0) {
        $("#checkedAll").prop("checked", true);
      }
      $(this).closest("table").closest("tr").prev("tr").find(".checkParent").prop("checked", true);

    } else {
      var isAllSiblingChecked = 0;
      $(this).closest("tr").nextAll("tr").find(".checkChild").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
          isAllSiblingChecked = 1;
      });

      $(this).closest("tr").prev("tr").find(".checkChild").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
          isAllSiblingChecked = 1;
      });

      if (isAllSiblingChecked == 0) {
        $(this).closest("table").closest("tr").prev("tr").find(".checkParent").prop("checked", false);
      }
      $("#checkedAll").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });

});
```

I've updated the fiddle here to see the working https://jsfiddle.net/shumaise/4zhhpwva/10/

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that the  selectors you have in place are always getting ALL checkchildren and ALL checkParents instead of just the nested ones. You need to make it more specific.

There's definitely a better way to do this, but as an example to show what I mean, on the `checkParent` click function, instead of `$(".checkChild")` which will grab all checkChildren on the page, you probably want to do something like `$(this).closest("tr").next("tr").find(".checkChild")`

That said, if you change your markup so that they are nested under a common ancestor that isn't shared with any other `checkChild` elements, that could be simplified so that the `.next` wouldn't be needed.

I've updated your fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/4zhhpwva/3/ so you can see it working...

Comment: your solution works well when checking a parent, it checks its child. but uncheck a child unchecks the parent without checking if siblings are unchecked or not. it shouldn't uncheck the parent if one of its child is checked. Uncheck the parent only if all child are unchecked. I've updated the fiddle. I'm able to stop the parent from being unchecked but even if all the child gets unchecked parent stays checked https://jsfiddle.net/4zhhpwva/4/